# Compatibility of Android Auto Companion App

Tags: android-auto

Is Android Auto companion app compatible with only US/UK networks?
I tried installing it on devices that have Android 5.0,5.1 from Play Store, but i get a message that the app is not compatible with the device.﻿

Comment: what is minsdkversion you specified??

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is limited to specific countries.  See this post on XDA for details

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=62262770&postcount=8

dave

Comment: Don't provide link only answers! Just think of the case the link gets broken. For more information, see ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center (item **Provide context for links**).